# CALCULATETABLE with OR statement in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do you make an OR statement in a calculate table query.
I have a statement where I select data from all rows of the city Davison but I not only want info from Davison, I also want information from the city Flint. How do I do this.

```
Table = CALCULATETABLE(datasetnew, datasetnew[City] = "Davison")
```

This is it, but i want something like this.

```
Table = CALCULATETABLE(datasetnew, datasetnew[City] = "Davison", or datasetnew[City] = "Flint")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Table = CALCULATETABLE(datasetnew, datasetnew[City] IN {"Davison", "Flint" })
```

Comment: Thanks, are OR statements in general not accepted in powerBI?

Comment: Or statements are fine. There are usually several ways to achieve desired objectives in DAX and the IN statement is nice and short.

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned IN statement in DAX is nice and short, but one other way of writing it is as follows(using OR operator ||(double pipe))

```
Table = CALCULATETABLE(datasetnew, datasetnew[City] = "Davison" || datasetnew[City] = "Flint")
```